# (CLOSED) How to persist data across multiple AWS Lambda sessions?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, cloud

I know this has been discussed various times on the world wide web, but as a newbie, it's really hard for me to translate these answers into practical execution steps.

Basically, I am looking to have a few list variables in my Lambda script to persist their storage across multiple sessions and empty themselves in the end of the day. When the script runs, certain values will be generated and I want to append those values into the lists for use in the subsequent lambda sessions.

Based on my research, we can persist data via the S3, /tmp, or EFS method. But for something like a list, how can I achieve that?

**UPDATE**

---

Decided to create parameter stores which are free for my small scale of work. With parameter stores, I store my JSON data in string type and parse them into dict/JSON for processing. In the end of the function, I parse my value back into string before overwriting them into the existing parameter store. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Why not use a dynamodb to store the items of your list?

Comment: /tmp will only last as long as your Lambda execution environment stays warm.  It could be 30 minutes, it could be just the one run.  If you just need to keep a few variables around, Dynamo is a common solution.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers @AnonCoward and Marcin. Let me search for lambda and dynamo related content. Not sure how we can store variables into Dynamo.

Comment: @Marcin i tried but couldn't find any tutorials on storing just variable values in DynamoDB. Most taught how to create an entire table which I think is a bit of an overkill. would you kindly lead me to the right path sensei?

Comment: You'll need a table in DynamoDB to store values in.

Comment: The costs of DynamoDB are likely to be a lot higher than S3.  I would recommend you use S3 for a few list variables.  What is in your list?  Can you convert your list to a delimited string or json and then just write the string content to an S3 file?